# Can we make a list using recyclerview when some items are on the top and some other are on the bottom?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

Is the any way to do that or should I use two recyclerview instead?

something like below:

```
__________
| Item 1 |
| Item 2 |
|        |
|        |
|        |
| Item 3 |
| Item 4 |
| Item 5 |
----------
```

instead of

```
__________
| Item 1 |
| Item 2 |
| Item 3 |
| Item 4 |
| Item 5 |
----------
```

Comment: Is the number of elements defined?

Comment: actually yes. what happened if it's no?

Comment: If the number is fixed then you can add empty views in between them. `what happened if it's no?` Nothing. You can still add an empty view but you'll have to do more work.

Comment: since recyclerview use adapter, so we need to use conditional (IF THEN) to accomplish that? if so, why don't you put your answer below so that I can accept yours?

Comment: You can do it with simple listview as well.